# In my CentOS 7.2 the symbolic link is not the whole directory

Tags: centos, symlink

This is the tutorial shows:

[image]

You can see the `/application/nginx -> /application/nginx-1.8.0`

But I follow the steps:

`[root@localhost nginx-1.8.0]# ll /application/nginx
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 12 5月  19 04:01 /application/nginx -> nginx-1.8.0/`

It is `nginx-1.8.0/`, there is no `/application` in front it, and sure the `nginx-1.8.0` is the Symbolic Link under the `/application`.

My operating system is `Cnet OS 7.2`

The tutorial operating system is `Cent OS 6.8`

The difference between the tutorial if is the system reason?

Comment: You probably didn't run the `ln` command exactly as written in the tutorial, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic mistake to get the targets wrong way round when using the `ln` command.

Make sure you use `ln <target> <linkname>` and see if it works.

The opening post could be a bit clearer, so that's all the help I can give.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to view the contents of the directory, you need a trailing slash when specifying the path. Like this:

```
ll /application/nginx/
```

Comment: No, I mean the `->`, it is point to `-> nginx-1.8.0/` but the `/application/nginx-1.8.0/`.

Comment: @qg_java Are you trying to make a relative link? if you you have to do `cd /application` `ln -s nginx-1.8.0 nginx`

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial created a link that resolves to an absolute path. You created a symbolic link that resolves to a relative path.

**Creates an absolute link:**

```
ln -s /application/nginx-1.8.0 /application/nginx
```

*`nginx` will always resolve to `/application/nginix-1.8.0`, even if you move `nginx` to a new directory.*

Use an absolute link if `nginx` might move and `/application/nginix-1.8.0` will never move.

**Creates a relative link:**

```
ln -s nginx-1.8.0 /application/nginx
```

*nginx will always resolve to `nginx-1.8.0` in whatever directory `nginx` is in*

When you use `-s` to create a symbolic link, the first parameter does not have to even exist in your filesystem. It's not an error to create a symbolic link to a file or path that doesn't exist yet.

Use this relative link if `nginix` will always exist in the same directory *relative* to `nginx-1.8.0`

**More relative link examples**

```
ln -s ../real alpha      # alpha will always point to real in alpha's parent directory
ln -s real alpha         # alpha will always point to real in alpha's directory
ln -s subdir/real alpha  # alpha will always point to subdir/real in alpha's directory
```